# fetch HTML Element object using javascript, mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, element, mootools1.2

Please check my HTML below:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="toogler">Demo1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="element">Demo1 Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="toogler">Demo1</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="element">Demo1 Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="toogler">Demo2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="element">Demo2 Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="toogler">Demo3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="element">Demo3 Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="toogler">Demo4</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="element">Demo4 Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $$('.toogler').each(function(e){
        alert(e);
        // this will alert all the toogler div object

    });
</script>
```

my problem is that how can i fetch the object of the next div with class element

if i have object of the first toogler then how can i get the object of the next first div which class 'element'

I don't want to give the ids to the elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can't alter the html output and refactor as suggested by oskar (best case), this works:

`e.getParent().getParent().getNext().getFirst().getFirst()` - it will return you the next div but it's slow.

unfortunately, tables break .getNext("div.element") as it's not a sibling.

another way that works is this (if their lengths match) - it will be MUCH faster if the reference is put in element storage as a 1-off:

```
var tooglers = $$("div.toogler"), elements = $$("div.element");
tooglers.each(function(el, i) {
    console.log(elements[i]);
    el.store("contentEl", elements[i]);
});
```

i don't like either solution though, not maintainable / scalable enough.

Answer (score 0):

You shall have to iterate through and check for the class one by one.

Comment: how can i iterate thorough the elements?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of assigning a toggler to the toggled element:

```
$$('.toogler').each(function(e, index){
    console.log($$('.element')[index]);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/aTaBB

Also, get rid of the table.

Comment: erm, calling the selector all the time is not gonna be very fast on a big table. _cached_ `$$("div.element")` will work better

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Element.getNext([match])](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getNext).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $$('.toogler').each(function(e){
        alert(e);

        // Get the next sibling with class element.
        var nextElement = e.getNext('.element');
        alert(nextElement);

    });
</script>
```